# Open PDF found with volatility

Tags: pdf, memory-dump, volatility

my task is to analyze a memory dump. I've found the location of a PDF-File and I want to analyze it with virustotal. But I can't figure out how to "download" it from the memory dump.

I've already tried it with this command:

```
python vol.py -f img.vmem dumpfiles -r pdf$ -i --name -D dumpfiles/
```

But in my dumpfile-directory there is just a .vacb file which is not a valid pdf.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have missed a command line argumenet from your command:

```
python vol.py -f img.vmem dumpfiles -r pdf$ -i --name -D dumpfiles/
```

If you are not getting a `.dat` file in your output folder you can add `-u`:

> -u, --unsafe          Relax safety constraints for more data

Can't test this with out access to the dump but you should be able to rename the `.dat` file created to `.pdf`.

So it should look something like this:

```
python vol.py -f img.vmem dumpfiles -r pdf$ -i --name -D dumpfiles/ -u
```

You can check out the documentation on the commands [here](https://github.com/volatilityfoundation/volatility/wiki/Command%20Reference#dumpfiles)

Answer (score -1):

VACB is "virtual address control block". Your output type seems to be wrong.
Try something like:

> $ python vol.py -f img.vmem dumpfiles --output=pdf --output-file=bla.pdf --profile=[your profile] -D dumpfiles/

or check out the cheat sheet: [here](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiq9erg9ZfKAhXCtxQKHeW3AeoQFggwMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fvolatility.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FCheatSheet_v2.3.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEnZnMEzLuj7N6GKsk-Xcoo2jNPjg&sig2=NS-GWTFxH5V1O6HBr0PA1Q)

Comment: Thanks for your hint.
But if I use the following command
python vol.py -f img.vmem dumpfiles --output=pdf --output-file=dumpfile/bla.pdf --profile=[myProfile] -D dumpfiles/ this error message shows up:
Supported formats are ['dot', 'greptext', 'html', 'json', 'sqlite', 'text', 'xlsx']
And without --output=pdf the created PDF is invalid. I will have a look at the cheatSheet :)